# Illegal sequential statement right shift multiplier

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I am trying to implement a Right shift multiplier and that is supposed to be the data path. Why does this code generate this error ?:

> Illegal sequential statement.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

entity data_path_module is
port (
a_in        : In    std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
b_in        : In    std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
rst_n       : In    std_logic;
p_in        : In    std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

a_out       : Out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
b_out       : Out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
valid_out   : Out   std_logic;
p_out       : Out   std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
);
end entity data_path_module;

architecture data_path_module_df of data_path_module is
signal tmp : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
P1 : process (a_in, b_in, rst_n, p_in)
begin
p_out   <= p_in + b_in when (a_in(0) = '1') else p_in;
a_out   <= b_in(0)  & a_in(2 downto 0);
b_out   <= '0'      & b_in(2 downto 0);

valid_out   <= '1';
end process P1;
end architecture data_path_module_df;
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told us what toolchain you are using, but the probable reason is that assignments using `when` are not supported within a process prior to VHDL-2008. Either activate 2008 mode in your tool, or use an `if` statement instead.

Answer (score 1):

When-else construct is concurrent statement as per  vhdl-93 standards. You are using it under process, as sequential statement.